# PC crashes when opening EXCEL-file in harmon.ie

Tags: excel, harmon.ie

We're using `harmon`.i.e, `enterprise edition`. For about two weeks we're having trouble with `Excel-files`.

When we open the files via Chrome on sharepoint, everything is fine. When we open the same file via harmon.ie nothing happens at first, an then the pc freezes. We have to do a hard-reset.

```
We've reinstalled harmon.ie -> no improvement
We've reinstalled Office x64 -> no improvement
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest to contact customer support from harmon.ie

Answer (score 0):

Please register the attached registry key then check again.
You said you use the Enterprise edition, you are hence a customer or an evaluator with a valid license file, in such case, you must report any issue to: support@harmon.ie

In text format:
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Mainsoft\Prefs\OpenFilesUsingScript]
@="false"

---- Jean[Registry key to register](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q9arenfmp35xc8b/OpenFilesUsingScript.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Thank you! We've tested the regkey on two machines and it looks promising. Thank you, very much!